# why is my <body> getting this added to it? (data-feedly-processed ="yes")

Tags: php, html, feedly

I'm working on a completely fresh site with php on my localhost. Currently no js or css and i'm not using any php frameworks or libraries. I have never used Feedly in my life!

This problem is stopping images from displaying...

Can anyone think what could be causing `data-feedly-processed ="yes"` to be added to my body tag?

Comment: perhaps it is something your host adds?

Comment: Are you using some kind of browser plugin/extension/whatnot that might do that? In other words, if you download the page, e.g. with `wget`, do you still see this in your `<body>` tag?

Comment: not using any plugins at all. page source does not show it, but firebug does in it's inspector. chrome inspector does not show it...  either images are not showing? strange!

Comment: Although you say you're not using any plug-ins, I still bet at it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox may be inserting this information because you have the [Feedly](http://feedly.com/) extension installed.

Comment: bugger this was the case! didnt solve my problem with images not displaying unfortunately...